# Execute many db2 commands in one command

Tags: db2, db2-luw

can I run multiple db2 commands in one command?
i.e: from cmd:

```
db2cmd /c db2 /c connect to sample user sample_user using sample_pwd /c 
"SELECT * FROM table;"
```

I also tried the following:

```
db2 connect to sample user db2admin using pwd; EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL 
MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT * FROM alarms;
```

but didn't work with the following error:

> SQL0104N An unexpected token "EXPORT" was found following
>   "". Expected tokens may include: "NEW". SQLSTATE=42601

as an example, for VERTICA, vsql tool, this can be done this way:

```
vsql -h localhost -U user -w pwd -c "SELECT * FROM alarms" -A -o 
"alarms.csv" -F "|" -P footer=off -q
```

Comment: Separate them using ";" and make it a single string

Comment: I tried something like this:
`db2 connect to sample user db2admin using pwd; EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT * FROM alarms;`
returned an error:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "EXPORT" was found following "<identifier>".
Expected tokens may include:  "NEW".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: "db2" is not a command

Comment: ok let me explain with another example, for instance with VERTICA , we have:
`vsql -h localhost -U user -w pwd -c "SELECT * FROM alarms" -A -o "alarms.csv" -F "|" -P footer=off -q`

Comment: have you tried `db2 "connect to ... ; export ..."`?

Comment: no this didn't work also

Comment: You will at some point need the terminator flag `-t` to indicate commands a terminated with a semi-colon otherwise it treats it as one big thing to run together. 

The "normal" way to do this is put the things to run into a script file and execute that script file with something like `db2 -tf bunch_of_sql.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using Microsoft Windows db2cmd.exe .

Your question has nothing to do with Db2 per se, but it is instead more about `CMD` (cmd.exe) scripting syntax, a legacy scripting language for batch files by Microsoft that still works on Windows-10, and which also works in `db2cmd.exe`.

In a db2cmd.exe shell you can use the "&&" sequence between distinct Db2 commands (and each such command must have the `db2` prefix). Additionally each such command line has to escape any of the characters that are *special characters* to the shell itself. By default the escape character is a caret (^) symbol.

For example `db2 connect to dbname && db2 ^"export to alarms.csv of del ... select ^* from alarms^" && db2 connect reset`

( I show the ^ before any " that you might want to pass to Db2-CLP ).

But that `&&` will require that each command returns a zero exit code, which might not be what you want, although it is usually the safest option. If a previous command fails then subsequent commands will not run.

If you want to tolerate some non-zero exit codes, use bracketing `( ... )` to group commands, and then use the `&&` or `&` outside the brackets depending on your requirements. You can read about CMD scripting in any good book, plenty of examples online.

However, when scripting for Db2 on Windows , it can be much wiser to append all of the commands (without the Db2 prefix) into a plain text file, and then ask the Db2 clp to execute the text file via the syntax `db2 -tvf texfile`.  Doing it this way lets you add conditional logic inside the textfile, handle exceptions , avoid shell escaping requirements, etc. If you encapsulate all your logic inside a script, it makes it easier to test, and also easier to run from a single `db2cmd /c ....` command-line.

If you want to make a batch file (*.bat or *.cmd) that does not need the `db2cmd` prefix to be invoked, you can alter your batch file to have a few lines at the start of the batch file to re-execute itself via `db2cmd.exe`. This works better if your `db2cmd.exe` is already on the `PATH` environment variable, but if that is not the case then you can fully-qualify the absolute pathname to your `db2cmd.exe` inside the batch file. The lines to add at the start of the batch file are:

```
@rem re-execute via db2cmd if running from cmd.exe
@echo off
if "%DB2CLP%"=="" db2cmd /c /i /w "%0" %* & goto :EOF
db2 connect to sample user db2admin using pwd
if errorlevel 1 @echo "Failed to connect to database " && @goto :EOF
db2 "EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT * FROM alarms"
if errorlevel 3 @echo "Export from Db2 failed" && @goto :EOF
```

Additionally on Windows, you can use Powershell scripting to maniuplate Db2 databases, and you can also use Windows subsystem for unix to run Unix-style shell scripts in some configuration.

Comment: Thank you @mao, so eventually what worked is this:
from the DB2 CLP:
`db2 connect to SAMPLE user db2admin using pwd && db2 -r "C:/Users/User/Desktop/alarms.csv" "SELECT * FROM alarms"`

but if I try to do this from the Windows CMD, say:
`db2cmd db2 connect to sample user db2admin using qscgywdvhu363 && db2 -r "C:/Users/EliasGhali/Desktop/alarms.csv" "SELECT * FROM alarms"`
this doesn't work

Comment: See updated answer. You cannot concatenate CLP commands unless each command has its own `db2' prefix and unless you use the `&&` or `&` beween each command. That's why it's better to use scriptfiles.

Comment: eventually what I used is from powershell:
`set-item -path env:Db2CLP -value "**$$**" ; db2 connect to SAMPLE user db2admin using pwd ; db2 -r "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alarms_20180327085700.csv" "SELECT * FROM alarms"`

Comment: but basically your answer led me to this solution so I'll set it as the correct answer thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your example's most direct comparison in Db2-land would be [clpplus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.clpplus.doc/doc/r0054268.html?pos=2) which lets you specify the database but you also have to provide login information (including a password or you can be prompted for it).

Within the `db2cmd` and `db2` framework you have a couple options but most likely will want to use a script file.

One option: Set the registry variable [DB2DBDFT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005657.html?pos=2) to your default database. Personally, I dislike this option because it causes an implicit connection to a database that you may not have intended.

One option: Put your series of commands into a file and run that file. This is the more traditional way of running multiple commands. Commands can be terminated with a semi-colon and newline (it understands DOS and Unix differences here). You can use a different terminator by using `-td @` (for example). You would then invoke `db2 -tf file.sql`.

One option: A batch file. It's similar to above but you'd use the db2cmd environment to execute a batch that has the db2 commands in it. `db2cmd` gets you an appropriate environment for working with Db2. If you connect to a database in this environment you stay connected until you issue a `CONNECT RESET`, a `TERMINATE`, are forcibly disconnected, or your environment exits. So your batch file would simply have:

```
db2 connect to sample user db2admin using pwd
db2 "EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT * FROM alarms"
```

(note the quotes to keep the command line from substituting all the filenames in the current working directory where the * is)

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1-st:

```
db2cmd /i /w /c "db2 ^"connect to sample^" & db2 ^"values 1^" & db2 connect reset"
```

2-nd:
You may set the following Windows system environment variable `DB2CLP` to the value `**$$**` and run db2 commands from windows `cmd` directly afterwards like this:

```
db2 "connect to sample" & db2 "values 1" & db2 connect reset
```